# iOS: NSUserDefaults Warning When I Try to Insert an "int" Value

Tags: ios, warnings, int, nsuserdefaults

In my app I wish to save at some point an "int" value in NSUserDefaults, and it gives me warning about the value not being of an "id" type and being an "int". i don't get this warning if I try to insert an NSString.

Here are the details.

The code I have written:

```
int currentCategoryForUserDefaults = currentCategory; //"cuurentCategory" is an enum value.

NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:currentCategoryForUserDefaults forKey:@"currentCategoryForUserDefaults"];
```

The warning I get (for the 3rd line):

```
Semantic Issue : Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id'
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [setInteger:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger%3aforKey%3a) instead of `setObject:forKey:`. An integer is not an object, it's a primitive type.

Then, you can retrieve it with [integerForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/integerForKey%3a).

Another option is to wrap your integer into a `NSNumber` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName` instead or wrap your *int* value into *NSNumber* and this will be exactly what debugger wants from you.